# create a span inside a div dynamically in vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using an existing web app created using vue.js. and below is the code.

```
function () {
                var e = this,
                    t = e.$createElement,
                    n = e._self._c || t;
                return e.message.text && "human" === e.message.type ? n("div", {
                    staticClass: "message-text"
                }, [e._v("\n  " + e._s(e.message.text) + "\n")]) : e.message.text && e.shouldRenderAsHtml ? n("div", {
                    staticClass: "message-text",
                    domProps: {
                        innerHTML: e._s(e.botMessageAsHtml)
                    }
                }) : e.message.text && "bot" === e.message.type ? n("div", {
                    staticClass: "message-text"
                }, [e._v("\n  " + e._s(e.shouldStripTags ? e.stripTagsFromMessage(e.message.text) : e.message.text) + "\n")]) : e._e()
            }
```

and here is my `n` function

```
function l(e, t) {
            function n(e, t, n, i) {
                console.log(typeof e + "\t" + typeof t + "\t" + typeof n + "\t" + typeof i);
                return function () {
                    if (n in t) {
                        return function () {
                            if (i && "object" === He()(e[n])) {
                                return f()({}, l(t[n], e[n], i), l(e[n], t[n], i));
                            }

                            return function () {
                                if ("object" === He()(e[n])) {
                                    return f()({}, e[n], t[n]);
                                }
                                return t[n];
                            }();
                        }();
                    }
                    return e[n];
                }();
            }
            var i = arguments.length > 2 && void 0 !== arguments[2] && arguments[2];
            return k()(e).map(function (r) {
                var o = n(e, t, r, i);
                return Ke()({}, r, o);
            }).reduce(function (e, t) {
                return f()({}, e, t);
            }, {});
        }
```

The above code basically creates a div tag with class name as `message-text`, I want to create a `span` inside this div. I am not at all good with vue.js and the code seems pretty confusing. please help me out in creating a `span` inside this `div`.

Comment: That looks like a render function that has been compiled from a template, it's not really something that is easy to mess around with.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a compiled code and minified probably. But if you can't get the uncompiled version I would try and simplify the code as it has a spaghetti if else.

```
function(){
        var e = this,
            t = e.$createElement,
            n = e._self._c || t,
            result;

        if(e.message.text && "human" === e.message.type){
            result = n("div", {staticClass: "message-text"}, [e._v("\n  " + e._s(e.message.text) + "\n")]) 
        }else{
            if(e.message.text && e.shouldRenderAsHtml){
                result = n("div", {staticClass: "message-text",domProps: {innerHTML: e._s(e.botMessageAsHtml)}})
            }else{
                if(e.message.text && "bot" === e.message.type){
                    if(e.shouldStripTags){
                        result = n("div", {staticClass: "message-text"}, [e._v("\n  " + e._s(e.stripTagsFromMessage(e.message.text)) + "\n")])
                    }else{
                        result = n("div", {staticClass: "message-text"}, [e._v("\n  " + e._s(e.message.text) + "\n")])
                    }
                } else {
                    result = e._e();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

You probably need to look into function n which is taking the arguments "div" as string and css class as object "message-text" with other props like innerHTML...

Comment: Thanks friend for that quick tip. I have got the function you were talking about and added to my question. Can you please take a look and help me out. Thanks

Comment: feels like not the right function to me. funciton n in the context of your first funciton is not called "n" it's actually `e.$createElement` Or `e._self._c`  and e stands for this